# Can you control an already open instance of VLC with the VLC python module?

Tags: vlc, libvlc, python-vlc

For my program I need to control an already open instance of VLC (I just want to increase/decrease the volume and make it pause), but I do not know if that is even possible as it seems you have to create instances to control them. Just wondering if anyone knew a way to do this? The following doesn't work presumably because VLC is playing before the media_player instance is created.

```
media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer()

def upvol():

    value = media_player.audio_get_volume()
    value = value + 5
    media_player.audio_set_volume(value)
    
  

def downvol():
    
    value = media_player.audio_get_volume()
    value = value - 5
    media_player.audio_set_volume(value)
```

Additionally, is there a way to make attempt to open any arbitrary file type?

Comment: Did you figure this out?